# find element with exactly the same properties

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I'm creating a test in Eclipse using selenium webdriver and java. I've got a page where I'd like to click a button with the following code:

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen1078" class="x-btn-text">Add</button>
```

The problem is that this exact same line (except for the id) is used earlier in the code so when I use the following line of code it will click the first item whereas I'd like to click one that is further down the code page.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-text' and text()='Add']")).click();
```

I can't use the ID as the ID"s are auto generated (a pain in the butt), so there is no unique identifier. I tried using the complete Xpath for the second button but this is not working and just too long.

Is there a way to determine how many times this exact line of code (exact except for the ID) is present and then select the second or even third if there are more then two?

======================================

Based on the answer below provided by @drkthng I've updated the question. Here is the working code:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Add']"));
System.out.println("There are "+listOfElements.size()+" buttons with the text 'Add'");

if(listOfElements.size() >= 2) {
  listOfElements.get(1).click();
}
```

This results in a click on the correct button and a print:
There are 2 buttons with the text 'Add'

Comment: what is the size of the listOfElements?

Comment: Also, it would help if you could post some more HTML

Comment: Please remove the monologue and trim it down to only the relevant parts so future readers can understand the question and make some use of it. Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE).

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I've updated the original question and trimmed it down. I've moved the 'old' content below so as not to loose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for the 2nd button directly via xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-text' and text()='Add'][2]")).click();
```

Or since you asked, you can also do it via a list of elements

> Is there a way to determine how many times this exact line of code
>   (exact except for the ID) is present

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-text' and text()='Add']");

if(listOfElements.size() >= 2) {
  listOfElements.get(1).click();
}
```

* if you go for indexing withing xpath, indexing starts with 1. In the second approach indexing starts with 0!

Comment: Thanks but neither option seemed to work.  I've updated my original question based on your answer as this comment box won't let me get enough characters in.

Comment: Not sure if what I added to the original question helps you but the entire code is just waayyy too much (see the xpath's, the first one is 19 div's deep and the second one 35)

Comment: can you tell me how many elements are found? -> print listOfElements.size()

Comment: Now this is interesting, if I add .size() so as to get the following line (   List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen']"));
    System.out.println("number of hits = "+listOfElements.size()); )the result is: number of hits = 1
Which I don't get as I can clearly see the button there...

Comment: yes, but 1 means that there is one button -> why are you surprised?

Comment: OK, I've added the code I use and some pictures to clarify what I'm doing. Hope this helps

Comment: If it finds only one where I expect at least two to be found, is there a way to find the xpath of the element it finds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93693/discussion-between-drkthng-and-hugo).

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what the difference is between what I had after I implemented drkthng's solution and what I now use but it is working! (and that's all I needed).
Here is the working code:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Add']"));
System.out.println("There are "+listOfElements.size()+" buttons with the text 'Add'");

if(listOfElements.size() >= 2) {
  listOfElements.get(1).click();
}
```

This results in a click on the correct button and a print:
There are 2 buttons with the text 'Add'

ORIGINAL QUESTION DIALOG: TOO LONG TO BE USEFULL BUT DID NOT WANT TO WASTE IT

I'm creating a test in Eclipse using selenium webdriver and java. I've got a page where I'd like to click a button with the following code:

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen1078" class="x-btn-text">Add</button>
```

The problem is that this exact same line (except for the id) is used earlier in the code so when I use the following line of code it will click the first item whereas I'd like to click one that is further down the code page.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-text' and text()='Add']")).click();
```

I can't use the ID as the ID"s are auto generated (a pain in the butt), so there is no unique identifier. I tried using the complete Xpath for the second button but this is not working and just too long.

Is there a way to determine how many times this exact line of code (exact except for the ID) is present and then select the second or even third if there are more then two?

======================================

Based on the answer below provided by @drkthng I've updated the question. The suggestion to use the following code resulted in a 'NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element'. I alse tried changing the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vffi.jpg), to [3] or [4] to check if there are even more instances but these led to the same error.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Add'][2]")).click();
```

I then tried the second option but when this did not work either I added a print command to see what was defined as ListOfElements

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen']"));
System.out.println("test"+listOfElements); /** I added this bit */
if(listOfElements.size() >= 2) {
  listOfElements.get(1).click();
}
```

It still does not click the button and the following is printed

```
test[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (b5689768-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f92cc3c41d33)] -> xpath: //button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Add']]]
```

If I change the .get(1) to .get(0) so that the first button should be clicked still nothing happens.

======================================

Not sure if this helps but this is the line of code for the first button

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen235" class="x-btn-text">Add</button>
```

and this is the full Xpath

```
/html/body/div[19]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em/button
```

This is the code for the second button (the one I want to click)

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen558" class="x-btn-text">Add</button>
```

and this is its full Xpath

```
/html/body/div[35]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em/button
```

======================================

More information:

OK, I'm using the following script:

```
/** I start of in the Main application window and This bit opens the first popup */
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath menu")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='x-menu-item-text' and text()='Popup 1']")).click();

/** The first popup is open. I then select an option in a dropdown an click search */ 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("searchRoleFieldId")));
driver.findElement(By.id("searchRoleFieldId")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-item' and text()='Option 1']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-item' and text()='Option 1']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='search']")).click();

/** I then select one of the search results and click the Edit button, this results in popup 2 being opened (edit window) */
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2' and text()='Result1']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2' and text()='Result 1']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Edit']")).click();

/** The second popup is open. I don't need to do anything in this screen other then to click a button (address) to view which addresses are linked to this Option 1. Clickin the addres button opens popup 3 */
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Address']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Address']")).click();

/** The third popup is open. Now in this window I can see which addresses are available for Option 1. I would like to add an address by clicking the add button */
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen'][2]")).click(); /** this does nothing  but when I remove the [2] bit the edit button on the first popup is click and opens a window to add a new Result*/

List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen']"));
System.out.println("number of hits = "+listOfElements.size());
if(listOfElements.size() >= 2) {
  listOfElements.get(0).click();
}
```

[image]
[image]